# Push a specif author's products to the top of a search result in Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my site I have multiple people who sell products on my woocommerce store. Many times I sell the same products as my vendors and when people search for a product using the search function I'd like my products to be shown first in the query before the vendor's products.

I tried using the "posts_search_orderby" hook but nothing seems to be happening.

```
    add_filter( 'posts_search_orderby', function( $search_orderby ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return "{$wpdb->posts}.post_author LIKE '1' DESC, {$search_orderby}";
    });
```

Any idea's on what I can do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's my code for you future people with same issue.

```
    add_filter('posts_orderby','my_sort_custom',10,2);
function my_sort_custom( $orderby, $query ){
    global $wpdb;

    if(!is_admin() && is_search()) 
        $orderby =  $wpdb->prefix."posts.post_author ASC, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date DESC";

    return  $orderby;
}
```

This works for me because I'm of course the first author on my site and i organized it by ascending author number.